# PHP: How to change part of XML using DomElement

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to make a function that changes part of an XML using XPath. I used part of someone else post:

```
/*********************************************************************
Function to replace part of an XML
**********************************************************************/
function replacePartofXML($element, $methodName, $methodValue, $xml, $newPartofXML)
{
    $xpathstring = "//" . $element . "[@$methodName = \"$methodValue\"]";
    $xml->xpath($xpathstring);

    //$domToChange = dom_import_simplexml($xml->xpath($xpathstring));
    $domToChange = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
    $domReplace  = dom_import_simplexml($newPartofXML);
    $nodeImport  = $domToChange->ownerDocument->importNode($domReplace, TRUE);
    $domToChange->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeImport, $domToChange);

    return($xml);
}
```

What I want to do is return the appended XML. I can't use dom_import_simplexml($xml->node->node) as my XML has many repeating element (but they have different ID reason why I am trying to use xpath)

The commented line does not work either as xpath returns an array and dom_import_simplexml is cannot import arrays.

Thanks for you input

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first element returned by `xpath()` in case you believe the target element is unique (no-element-returned checking omitted) :

```
$domToChange = dom_import_simplexml($xml->xpath($xpathstring)[0]);
```

or iterate through the return value of `xpath()` and replace one by one.

Comment: $domToChange = dom_import_simplexml($xml->xpath($xpathstring)[0]); I tried this and it does not compile correclty (well php sees an error). and yes, my target element is unique

Comment: It works, sorry, dreamweaver see;s an error, but the php does do it correclty... Thanks a lot... More than thanks, been struggling with this for 2 days...

Comment: @JSChasle consider [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved the problem in question